# How do I organize Information in different cells into specific columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a large document and the information is randomly arranged and I need to organize it in columns. The header of the document is like;

`name | address | email_address | date`

The email address are in the name or date column, so it's all mixed up. Is there any solution to arrange the correct data to the correct columns (other than drag and drop)?

Comment: Unless there's a pattern, you'd have to do a macro like "for all cells with `@` cut/paste to email; then all cells with number, cut/paste to address. But then, what else would to use as identifiers?

Comment: Sounds to me like you've imported a file without delimiting the columns correctly. Try reimporting as a tab-separated file.

Comment: There is no pattern in my sheet and I didn't import it. I have received it like that to arrange it... Thank you!